# Complex numbers proof using modulus and conjugates

Tags: complex-numbers

The question:

If $\alpha ,  \beta$ are complex numbers where $\alpha \ne \beta$ and $|\alpha|=1$.

Prove that $|\frac{\alpha \overline{\beta}-1}{\alpha-\beta}| =1$

Answer (score 1):

$$|\alpha\bar\beta-1|=|\bar\beta-\alpha^{-1}|=|\bar\beta-\bar\alpha|=|\beta-\alpha|$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a visual demonstration. If you are looking for a mathematically rigorous answer, @Kenta S has beautifully solved it in a single line.

You may know that when we multiply complex numbers, their modulus get multiplied and their arguments get added up.

WLOG, lets represent the complex numbers on the argand plane as:

[image]

Now, conjugate of a complex number is obtained by reflecting the number about the real number line

[image]

As $\alpha$ is unimodular, so multiplying it with any complex number would mean a rotation by an angle $arg(\alpha)$

[image]

$|α\barβ−1|$ is the distance between the point $1$ and the point $α\barβ$

Similarly, $|α-β|$ is the distance between the points corresponding to $α$ and $β$. i.e. the length of the segments represented by f and g in purple in the following diagram:

[image]

Which can be shown equal by showing the following orange triangles congruent. *Proof left
for the reader*

[image]

Hence, $|α-β|=|α\barβ−1|$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

It comes down to proving
$$\biggl|\frac{\alpha \bar{\beta}-1}{\alpha-\beta} =1\biggr|^2 =1,$$
i.e., since  $\;|z|^2=z\bar z$,
$$ \frac{\alpha \bar\beta -1}{\alpha-\beta}\,\frac{\bar\alpha \beta -1}{\bar\alpha-\bar\beta}=1\iff (\alpha \bar\beta -1)(\bar\alpha \beta -1)=(\alpha-\beta)(\bar\alpha-\bar\beta).$$